# JPA entity with GlassFish 4 and PostGIS

Tags: postgresql, jpa, glassfish, eclipselink, postgis

I'm trying to create a JPA entity with GlassFish 4 using PostgreSQL 9.1 and PostGIS 1.5.

I've created/configured a data source in GlassFish by adding the `postgres-jdbc` and `postgis-jdbc` JARs into the domain/lib directory.

I've created a simple entity `MyPoint` that handles a PostGIS point:

```
@Entity
public class MyPoint implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1595466016586244423L;

    @Id
    private int id;

    @Column(columnDefinition="Geometry")
    private Point the_geom;

    public MyPoint() {
        super();
    }   

    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }   

    public Point getPoint() {
        return this.the_geom;
    }

    public void setPoint(Point p) {
        this.point = p;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.lang.Object#toString()
     */
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Point [id=" + id + ", point=" + the_geom + "]";
    }   
}
```

And a point home with the `createPoint()` method like this:

```
@Stateless(name="PointHome")
public class PointHome {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public MyPoint createPoint(MyPoint point){
        entityManager.persist(point);
        return point;
    }       
}
```

On war deployment, the table `MyPoint` with columns `id` and `the_geom` are created. Column `the_geom` is of type `geometry`. Here is the table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE mypoint
(
    id integer NOT NULL,
    the_geom geometry,
    CONSTRAINT mypoint_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id )
)
```

The problem is when invoking the `persist()` method on the entity manager:

```
MyPoint z = new MyPoint();
z.setPoint(new Point(6, 43));
System.err.println(z);
zoneHome.createPoint(z);
```

I've got an `org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException`.

> Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException Internal
>   Exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: parse error -
>   invalid geometry Hint: You must specify a valid OGC WKT geometry type
>   such as POINT, LINESTRING or POLYGON
>
> ...
>
> Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: parse error -
>   invalid geometry Hint: You must specify a valid OGC WKT geometry type
>   such as POINT, LINESTRING or POLYGON Error Code: 0 Call: INSERT INTO
>    MYPOINT (ID, THE_GEOM) VALUES (?, ?)
>
> bind => [2 parameters bound] Query: InsertObjectQuery(Point [id=0,
>   point=POINT(6 43)])

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Use Hibernate Spatial extension (http://www.hibernatespatial.org/) with altered `MyPoint` entity:

```
@Entity
public class MyPoint implements Serializable {
    //...
    @Type(type="org.hibernate.spatial.GeometryType")
    private Point the_geom;
    //...
}
```